# How to use d3.drag()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What causes the following TypeError?

> TypeError: callback is undefined

My code looks like this:

```
    <script>
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .call(drag)

    var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", start)

    function start(d){
    };

    </script>
```

Comment: @altocumulus Too bad you edited it, I was enjoying `d3.drug` a lot... Actually, this can be the name of the new plugin I'll write...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Nice, a plugin! Would you mind sharing more details? Can I serve as a beta tester? Pass `d3.drug` around, so to speak...

Comment: `d3.drug` will be a plugin so full of anti-patterns and nonsense snippets that users will quickly understand the name choice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the value of `drag` at the time you use it, so it takes its default value, `undefined`.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .call(drag)
```

This is because the declaration of `drag` (`var drag`) is hoisted to the beginning of the code. You can fix the problem by setting the value of `drag` before you use it:

```
var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", start)

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .call(drag)

function start(d){
};
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please share what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: It wasn't me downvoting this, but your assumption about the usage of `start()` is wrong. This function is not part of the problem; it's the correct way to create a drag handler in D3 and register a listener, namely `start(d)` for the start event. I reckon, this was the reason for the downvote. Nonetheless, your first assumption about the declaration `var drag` being hoisted while the assignment is done after the use in `.call(drag)` is spot-on and the true reason for the error. I suggest you delete the second part of your post and add a snippet showing the corrected code instead.